# Deleting rows that are duplicated in one column based on the conditions of another column

Tags: r, date, duplicates

Here is an example of my data set;

```
Date      Time(GMT) Depth Temp  Salinity Density    Phosphate
24/06/2002  1000    1           33.855          0.01
24/06/2002  1000    45          33.827          0.01
01/07/2002  1000    10  13.26   33.104  24.873  0.06
01/07/2002  1000    30  12.01   33.787  25.646  0.13
08/07/2002  1000    5   13.34   33.609  25.248  0.01
08/07/2002  1000    40  12.01   34.258  26.011  1.33
15/07/2002  1000    30  12.04   34.507  26.199  0.01
22/07/2002  1000    5   13.93   33.792  25.269  0.01
22/07/2002  1000    30  11.9    34.438  26.172  0.08
29/07/2002  1000    5   13.23   34.09   25.642  0.01
```

I want to delete duplicate rows so that I only have one row per date, I want to do this based on the Depth, I would like to keep the row with the greatest (deepest) depth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Lets say you have data in df

```
df = df[order(df[,'Date'],-df[,'Depth']),]
df = df[!duplicated(df$Date),]
```

Comment: Elegant, much better than my one. +1

Comment: You should probably switch `duplicated[df$Date]` to `duplicated(df$Date)`. Other than that, this is the only real R solution here

Answer (score 20):

Here's one way to do it in a single dplyr call:

```
# Remove any duplicates
df <- df %>%
  arrange(Date, -Depth) %>%
  filter(duplicated(Date) == FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice. I would prefer `!duplicated(Date)` instead of `duplicated(Date) == FALSE`.

Answer (score 12):

Introducing a `data.table` solution which will be the fastest way to solve this (assuming `data` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(data)[order(Date, -Depth)], by = "Date")
```

---

Just another way:

```
setDT(data)[data[, .I[which.max(Depth)], by=Date]$V1]
```

Answer (score 6):

You might also use dplyr's `arrange()` instead of order (I find it more intuitive):

```
df <- arrange(df, Date, -Depth)
df <- df[!duplicated(df$Date),]
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be not the fastest approach if your data frame is large, but a fairly strightforward one. This might change the order of your data frame and you might need to reorder by e.g. date afterwards. Instead of deleting we split the data by date, in each chunk pick a row with the maximum date and finally join the result back into a data frame

```
data = split(data, data$Date)
data = lapply(data, function(x) x[which.max(x$Depth), , drop=FALSE])
data = do.call("rbind", data)
```

Comment: maybe you can replace `split+lapply` by `by`.

Comment: I was writing a similar answer to yours, but you beat me to it. I've added helen.h's actual data to your post so the desired output is shown. I hope that's alright.

Comment: @agstudy I'd love to, but do not have R installed where I am now to try it out :)

Answer (score 3):

```
# First find the maxvalues
maxvals = aggregate(df$Depth~df$Date, FUN=max)
#Now use apply to find the matching rows and separate them out
out = df[apply(maxvals,1,FUN=function(x) which(paste(df$Date,df$Depth) == paste(x[1],x[2]))),]
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using dplyr's `distinct` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(column, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't address the second part of the question ("...based on the conditions of another column").