# Removing duplicates of only one variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I would like to condense by removing duplicates, but only of a certain variable.  In the example below, I would only like to remove duplicates of `user_id` when the `plan_type = subscriber`.  The `output` of is shown below of how the sample data should be condensed.

I have tried `unique()` but it will not work because there may be multiple occurrences of the same `user_id` where `plan_type = PPG` and this data should remain.

Any suggestions that do not include multiple steps of subsetting and then rebinding two dataframes?

```
> foo
      user_id  plan_type
16435    6264 subscriber
31518   10050 subscriber
31520   10050 subscriber
7576    11174 subscriber
19744   11186 subscriber
19745   11186 subscriber
46108   20348 subscriber
5293    31641 subscriber
5294    31641 subscriber
5295    31641        PPU


> output
      user_id  plan_type
16435    6264 subscriber
31520   10050 subscriber
7576    11174 subscriber
19745   11186 subscriber
46108   20348 subscriber
5294    31641 subscriber
5295    31641        PPU

> dput(foo)
structure(list(user_id = c(6264L, 10050L, 10050L, 11174L, 11186L, 
11186L, 20348L, 31641L, 31641L, 31641L), plan_type = c("subscriber", 
"subscriber", "subscriber", "subscriber", "subscriber", "subscriber", 
"subscriber", "subscriber", "subscriber", "PPU")), .Names = c("user_id", 
"plan_type"), row.names = c(16435L, 31518L, 31520L, 7576L, 19744L, 
19745L, 46108L, 5293L, 5294L, 5295L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011246/deleting-rows-that-are-duplicated-in-one-column-based-on-the-conditions-of-anoth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to subset only those observations where `user_id` is **not** duplicated **OR** `plan_type` is **not** "subscriber":

```
foo[!duplicated(foo$user_id) | foo$plan_type != "subscriber", ]
```

Using dplyr, this would be

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>% filter(!duplicated(user_id) | plan_type != "subscriber")
```

Comment: would just point out, your `dplyr` example keeps the first instance, while given example keeps the last of duplicated instances. This doesn't seem to be very important here, but may matter in certain scenarios.

Comment: @Aramis7d, OP didn't specify what particular row should be kept in case of duplicates that shall be removed so I'll just stick to my answer unless OP makes other specifications. In the end, it boils down to ordering the data before this step.

Comment: true. I inferred it from his example. Might be a total coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logic

```
subset(foo, (!duplicated(user_id) & plan_type == "subscriber")|
         plan_type %in% setdiff(unique(plan_type), "subscriber"))
#       user_id  plan_type
#16435    6264 subscriber
#31518   10050 subscriber
#7576    11174 subscriber
#19744   11186 subscriber
#46108   20348 subscriber
#5293    31641 subscriber
#5295    31641       PPU
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbind(unique(setDT(foo), by = "user_id"), foo[plan_type!= "subscriber"])
#    user_id  plan_type
#1:    6264 subscriber
#2:   10050 subscriber
#3:   11174 subscriber
#4:   11186 subscriber
#5:   20348 subscriber
#6:   31641 subscriber
#7:   31641        PPU
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input as `df`

```
df <-  read.table(text = '  indx    user_id  plan_type
16435    6264 subscriber
31518   10050 subscriber
31520   10050 subscriber
7576    11174 subscriber
19744   11186 subscriber
19745   11186 subscriber
46108   20348 subscriber
5293    31641 subscriber
5294    31641 subscriber
5295    31641        PPU', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

you can try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(plan_type, user_id) %>%
  slice(which.max(indx))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: plan_type, user_id [7]

   indx user_id  plan_type
  <int>   <int>      <chr>
1  5295   31641        PPU
2 16435    6264 subscriber
3 31520   10050 subscriber
4  7576   11174 subscriber
5 19745   11186 subscriber
6 46108   20348 subscriber
7  5294   31641 subscriber
```

you may also include the `plan_type == "subscriber"` filter if you want to, though it doesn't make a difference per the given example.

This can be done as:

```
df %>% 
  filter( plan_type == "subscriber") %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  slice(which.max(indx)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(plan_type != "subscriber"))
```

Comment: This will fail in OP's real data since they specified `there may be multiple occurrences of the same user_id where plan_type = PPG and this data should remain`

Comment: and I did mention OP can include a filter for that, to fit his actual data :) .
I designed my solution considering the example to be a complete representation of the actual set. But of course, if the inputs change, the solutions must change accordingly.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in this case, OP already specified additional requirements in his post so not taking these into account seems wrong to me

Comment: Fair enough. I guess OP should ideally change the example to include all possible scenarios. Anyways, i made some changes as well :)