# delete rows that have duplicates based on a column dependening on number of NAs in different column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to delete rows where column a has duplicate values based on the number of NAs in other columns. This is similar to this, but I can't get the counting NAs to work with the solutions there.

> [Deleting rows that are duplicated in one column based on the conditions of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011246/deleting-rows-that-are-duplicated-in-one-column-based-on-the-conditions-of-anoth)

Here is my toy dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("x","y","y","z","x", "z"), b = c(1,2,NA,4,8,3), c = c(NA,2,2,NA,NA,4), d= c(1:4,NA,NA))
```

which gives:

```
  a  b  c  d
1 x  1 NA  1
2 y  2  2  2
3 y NA  2  3
4 z  4 NA  4
5 x  8 NA NA
6 z  3  4 NA
```

I would like to only keep rows with unique values in column a, and keep only the rows with the least number of NAs in cols b & c (ignoring NAs in column d)

This is the code I came up with:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate(NAs= apply(is.na(cbind(b,c)), 1, sum)) %>%     
 group_by(a) %>%
 top_n(n=1, -NAs)
```

My problem is that top_n returns more than one row if there is a tie. In case of a tie, I just want the first row returned. And there's probably a better way to select columns in mutate than cbind. I also don't need the "NAs" variable i created using mutate. My desired output is this:

```
  a  b  c  d
  x  1 NA  1
  y  2  2  2
  z  3  4 NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@markus suggested this could be an answer too. Perhaps it's true, as it can be helpful to keep the code short in case of `dplyr`, otherwise you can often end up with quite verbose scripts.

However, the main part in my opinion is `rowSums` as it's already been highlighted.

```
df1 %>% 
arrange(a, rowSums(is.na(.[, c("b", "c")]))) %>% 
distinct(a, .keep_all = TRUE)

  a b  c  d
1 x 1 NA  1
2 y 2  2  2
3 z 3  4 NA
```

P.S. If speed is your concern, then indeed I'd try to use as little `dplyr` verbs as possible, as e.g. the approach with only `arrange` & `distinct` is 3x faster than other approaches with `group`, `slice`, `top_n`, `filter`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(NAs = rowSums(is.na(.[, c("b", "c")]))) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, -NAs) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(-NAs)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   a [3]
#  a         b     c     d
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 x         1    NA     1
#2 y         2     2     2
#3 z         3     4    NA
```

`rowSums` is a more efficient alternative to `apply(..., 1, sum)`.

---

You might also try `data.table`. The solution below should be really fast (but potentially less readable).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[df1[order(a, df1[, rowSums(is.na(.SD)), .SDcols = c("b", "c")]), .I[1], by = "a"]$V1]
#   a b  c  d
#1: x 1 NA  1
#2: y 2  2  2
#3: z 3  4 NA
```

Comment: This is not a different approach, but just if you'd like to keep it less verbose: `df1 %>%
  arrange(a, rowSums(is.na(.[, c("b", "c")]))) %>%
  distinct(a, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: @arg0naut Very nice. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different `dplyr` option:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(miss = rowSums(is.na(cbind(b,c)))) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(miss == min(miss)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-miss) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(miss = rowSums(is.na(cbind(b,c)))) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(dupl = seq_along(a)) %>%
  filter(miss == min(miss)) %>%
  filter(dupl == min(dupl)) %>%
  select(-miss, -dupl) %>%
  ungroup()
```