# Deleting rows that are duplicated in one column based on value in another column

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyverse

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011246/deleting-rows-that-are-duplicated-in-one-column-based-on-the-conditions-of-anoth). However, I did not manage to adopt that solution to my particular problem, hence the separate question.

An example dataset:

```
  id group
1  1   5
2  1 998
3  2   2
4  2   3
5  3 998
```

I would like to delete all rows that are duplicated in id and where group has value 998.
In this example, only row 2 should be deleted.

I tried something along those lines:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  subset((unique(by = "id") |  group != 998))
```

but got

> Error in is.factor(x) : Argument "x" is missing, with no default

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try replacing subset with the filter function (obviously follow the package guidelines) and use group_by(id) as Sotos just said a split second ago ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 filter(!any(n() > 1 & group == 998))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id group
  <int> <int>
1     2     2
2     2     3
3     3   998
```

In case you want to remove only the 998 entry from the group then,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 filter(!(n() > 1 & group == 998))
```

Comment: I applied this solution but leaving out ´any´ (like in your comment in TarJae's solution) to  both the example and my original dataset and it looks like this achieved the desired output. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(duplicated(id) & group=="998") 

anti_join(df, df1)
```

```
Joining, by = c("id", "group")
  id group
1  1     5
3  2     2
4  2     3
5  3   998
```

Comment: Not sure about OPs expected output, but If this is the case you can simply do `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!(n() > 1 & group == 998))`. I added `any` in my answer to remove all of the group that satisfies those criteria

Comment: Thanks Sotos. I am also not sure. I guess we wait.

Comment: I applied the solution as laid out in Sotos comment and it worked. Thank you very much to both of you!

Comment: @Sotos please add the comment to your answer. +1